# how to set a minimum zoom (and lock axis) on a camera in Cesium

Tags: javascript, cesiumjs

Using Cesium

I would like that my camera in my map.

I would like it to be always at least at a defined height from the floor.
Also, I would like to lock the rotation so that I can't never go over or under a certain angle (for exemple lock my camera to a hemisphere and not a full circle)

I can't find a proper way to do so. even in the documentation.

```
this.cameraService.setView({
  destination: data.destination || this.DEFAULT_POSITION,
  orientation: data.orientation || this.DEFAULT_ORIENTATION,
  endTransform: data.endTransform || Cesium.Matrix4.IdENTITY
});
```

wathever value I pass into destination or orientation, I want it to be at least (let's say) 1000height and clamped to some specific angles.